# Contents of DIV go outside DIV when DIV changes Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a DIV that changes its size when a link is clicked. When the link is clicked, the div animate()s to width: 0px, but the contents of that div is still visible on the outside of the div! How can I make the contents of the div not go outside the div, without explicitly setting its visibility to hidden? Maybe some kind of anti-overflow thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the CSS for the DIV:

```
overflow: hidden;
```